cómo seleccionar líneas previas en un merge?
d0 <- data.frame(
  cro = c("H014140001109828", "H014140001109828", "H014140001109828"),
  fcon = as.Date(c("2020-03-12", "2020-04-23", "2020-05-21")),
  jdate = as.numeric(as.Date(c("2020-03-12", "2020-04-23", "2020-05-21"))),
  l_dia = c("1200", "850", "550"))
)

d2 <- data.frame(
  fcon = as.Date(c("2020-03-09","2020-03-10","2020-03-11","2020-03-12",
                   "2020-04-19", "2020-04-20", "2020-04-21", "2020-04-22","2020-04-23",
                   "2020-05-18","2020-05-19", "2020-05-20", "2020-05-21")),
   temp = c("22","19","21","25","12","20","17","8","10","11","14","16","18","29","22")),
   jdate = as.numeric(as.Date(c("2020-03-09","2020-03-10","2020-03-11","2020-03-12",
                   "2020-04-19", "2020-04-20", "2020-04-21", "2020-04-22","2020-04-23",
                   "2020-05-18","2020-05-19", "2020-05-20", "2020-05-21")))
)

Debo unir los dos dframes, por el jdate o fcon coincidente, pero además tomar los valores de temp de los 3 días previos al jdate o fcon coincidente.
res <- cro = c("H014140001109828", "H014140001109828", "H014140001109828"),
       fcon =c("2020-03-09","2020-03-10","2020-03-11","2020-03-12",
               "2020-04-20", "2020-04-21", "2020-04-22","2020-04-23",
               "2020-05-19", "2020-05-20", "2020-05-21"),
       temp = c("22","19","21","25","20","17","8","10","18","29","22")
       ldia =c("1200","1200","1200","1200","850","850","850","850","550","550","550")

Creo que la solución puede ser un bucle, pero no sé cómo programarlo

Una solución sencilla con R base es hacer versiones de fecha +0, +1, +2 y +3 días y luego hacer un join con estas versiones, y concatenar cada resultado en un único data.frame.
Voy a trabajar directamente con fcon:
d0 <- data.frame(
  cro = c("H014140001109828", "H014140001109828", "H014140001109828"),
  fcon = as.Date(c("2020-03-12", "2020-04-23", "2020-05-21"))
)

d2 <- data.frame(
  fcon = as.Date(c("2020-03-09","2020-03-10","2020-03-11","2020-03-12",
                   "2020-04-19", "2020-04-20", "2020-04-21", "2020-04-22","2020-04-23",
                   "2020-05-18","2020-05-19", "2020-05-20", "2020-05-21")),
  temp = c("22","19","21","25","12","20","17","8","10","11","14","16","18"))

Es una versión más sencilla de tus datos, los necesarios para entender la idea.
d2$fcon0 <- d2$fcon + 0
d2$fcon1 <- d2$fcon + 1
d2$fcon2 <- d2$fcon + 2
d2$fcon3 <- d2$fcon + 3

Generamos 4 fechas nuevas despalzando 0, 1, 2 y 3 días.
final <- rbind(
  merge(d0, d2, by.x="fcon", by.y="fcon0")[, c('fcon', 'cro', 'fcon.y', 'temp')],
  merge(d0, d2, by.x="fcon", by.y="fcon1")[, c('fcon', 'cro', 'fcon.y', 'temp')], 
  merge(d0, d2, by.x="fcon", by.y="fcon2")[, c('fcon', 'cro', 'fcon.y', 'temp')],
  merge(d0, d2, by.x="fcon", by.y="fcon3")[, c('fcon', 'cro', 'fcon.y', 'temp')]
)

Hacemos un "join" entre los 2 data.frames por cada versión de fecha y concatenamos todo en un único resultado:
arrange(final, fcon)

         fcon              cro     fcon.y temp
1  2020-03-12 H014140001109828 2020-03-12   25
2  2020-03-12 H014140001109828 2020-03-11   21
3  2020-03-12 H014140001109828 2020-03-10   19
4  2020-03-12 H014140001109828 2020-03-09   22
5  2020-04-23 H014140001109828 2020-04-23   10
6  2020-04-23 H014140001109828 2020-04-22    8
7  2020-04-23 H014140001109828 2020-04-21   17
8  2020-04-23 H014140001109828 2020-04-20   20
9  2020-05-21 H014140001109828 2020-05-21   18
10 2020-05-21 H014140001109828 2020-05-20   16
11 2020-05-21 H014140001109828 2020-05-19   14
12 2020-05-21 H014140001109828 2020-05-18   11

